# sync 2 lists between different farms with event receiver

Tags: event-receivers, sync

I have to sync 2 same lists between 2 different farms . The original list is located in a SP 2007 farm and the destination is located in a SP 2013 farm. I have already an event receiver in SP 2007  list .Is it possible to add some code that adds/updates to the 2013 list? Is it possible via web services?

Answer (score 0):

You can use web services.
Also, you can use CSOM to create/update/delete items, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx#BasicOps_SPListItemTasks).

Item Add is easy to handle. Have you thought about update and delete of items in original list? How will you find the item to update in SP 2013 list when an item is updated in SP 2007? I am just trying to hint that you will have to maintain some mapping between items from SP 2007 to items in SP 2013 since IDs will most likely be different. So you can store the Id value from 2007 item in an additional field in 2013 (or you may have a field with unique value in the list.